# How to extract and count the number of similar-color dots from color image?

Tags: c++, image, opencv

I have a bunch of color images that have color dots on them. The dots are similar color but sometimes the color of dots might be also similar with the background image that I cannot extract them. The following images can be an example
[Green dots on IR train image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/evCfT.jpg)
I have tried to convert the color space from RGB to HSV; applied blur filter on H channel; applied sobel filter on H channel; converted H channel to binary image; applied shrinking and count the number of dots. But the result is not good. The result of train IR image, is shown below
[Resulting train image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GLfuc.png)

The white dots are indicating the dots I found, which are not very correct.

So how I extract (find) those green dots on the color image?

Thanks!

Comment: Scan the image per pixel and look for an exact match of your RGB values.  If you know how big your "color dots" are in pixels, you can count touching/adjacent matches and make sure that the size matches up to prevent false positives when an area of the background happens to match your dot.  You can also catch overlapping color dots this way as well with care.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan Thanks for your reply! But what if the green dots are not same pixel values and same size? Some are dark green or some are bright green, some are big or some are small?

Comment: You stated in your original problem that "dots are in the same color"  If they are not, will you know what they are somehow?

Comment: @MichaelDorgan I am sorry I should change my problem into "similar color" ! :)

Comment: Ok, then you need to define similar.  That can mean many many things.  Is light green and dark green the same.  What exactly is light and dark green?  A heuristic of some sort is needed.  Even something as simple as add the R,G,B triplet - if the values vary by more than some number, they aren't similar.  The problem here is the human eye thinks that most dark colors are very close, but slight differences in lighter colors are easily visible.  Same for R,G,B sensitivity.  But, as long as you keep what is similar close to some set value, I think it will give you a starting point.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan You are right. An example of dots can be found in http://www.engadget.com/2010/11/08/visualized-kinect-night-vision-lots-and-lots-and-lots-of-do/   But in my case, my background image is color image.

Comment: If the color of the background matches exact, then there is loss of information and you can only guess.  It does appear though that the brightness of the dot is proportional the the distance from the Kinect?  And also, the size of the dot would decrease, roughly some constant /distance from target?  With that, if you know size and color at a couple distances, you can compute expected value ranges for the dots (medium green dot should be X size, but bright should be bigger size.)  If the object was an exact match of the Kinect I/R color and uniformly away from the Kinect, it's invisible.

Comment: It seems though that the Kinect should be able to combat this by varying intensity over time or something?  Then, the image color would become visible as the power goes up and down on the emitter.  Not a Kinect expert though, so I'm not sure if it can do this.  More frames of animation to work with should help a lot though. BTW, I forgot that different material reflects dots at different rates so the color cannot be used for distance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an answer, you should know a minimum and maximum allowed dot size as well as a minimum and maximum allowed pixel color.  Because these are coming in via a Kinect, the color intensities cannot be directly matched, but within a very small delta, I expect you could check adjacent pixels for "good" values.  Basically look for "edges" in the images where the color intensity varies a bunch and see if those edges form dots of the correct size.  Play with how close the pixel colors have to be to get more or less accurate answers - more color difference means catching more dots, but false positives and visa-versa.

Not sure if this will get you quite what you need, but I think it will get you better than what you have now.

Comment: Thank you Michael!